# How to realize this in Transact SQL ( SQL Server 2008 )

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I just want an update trigger like this postgresql version... It seems to me there is no NEW. and OLD. in MSSQL?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."ts_create" () RETURNS trigger AS
DECLARE
BEGIN
  NEW.ctime := now();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Googled already, but nothing to be found unfortunately... Ideas?

Update:
Sth, like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr01 ON Auctions for insert
As
update auctions set mtime = GETDATE() where Id = inserted.Id;
```

or this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr01 ON Auctions for insert
As
inserted.ctime := GETDATE();
```

bothg dont work of course ;)

Comment: Why are you using a trigger for what should be a default constraint?

Comment: yah, bad example.. but i'd need it for "mtime" then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) the pseudo tables are called [INSERTED and UPDATED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

I would use a default constraint on the ctime column for your particular example, however:

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema.tbl_name_insert ON schema.tbl_name
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        UPDATE schema.tbl_name
        SET mtime = getdate()
        FROM schema.tbl_name
        INNER JOIN JOIN INSERTED
            ON schema.tbl_name.PK = INSERTED.PK
```

or

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema.tbl_name_insert ON schema.tbl_name
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        UPDATE schema.tbl_name
        SET mtime = getdate()
        FROM schema.tbl_name
        WHERE schema.tbl_name.PK IN (SELECT PK FROM INSERTED)
```

A trigger fires once for an entire INSERT statement, so, in general, the INSERT AND DELETED tables may contain multiple rows.

Comment: @David Updated to include a couple examples.

Answer (score 3):

For triggers, SQL makes available virtual tables named "inserted" and "deleted". Here's a sample routine trigger I've had in place for months (SQL 2005):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MAP].[TR_iu_MyTable__LastUpdated]
 on [dbo].[MyTable]
 after insert, update

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    UPDATE MAP.MyTable
     set LastUpdated = getdate()
     where MyTableId in (select MyTableId from inserted)

GO
```

(Note that this is an "after" trigger, so I only need to run an UPDATE.)

Answer (score 1):

First, for the insert you can set a default value to be GETDATE().

Then on update, try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TimeUpdater ON Auctions FOR UPDATE
AS
UPDATE auctions 
SET mtime = GETDATE() 
FROM UPDATED u
WHERE Id = u.Id
```